# PHP declare class variable from another instance

Tags: php, class, variable-assignment

I have a hard time figuring out how to add a variable value to an instantiated class in php,
I've been looking at the reflectionClass and tried to return an assigned variable, and now I'm ended up with a getter setter.
I would really appreciate some help, here's an example of my code:

```
class controller
{

    public $models;

    private $load;

    public function __construct() 
    {
        $this->load = new loader();
    }

    public function action_being_run()
    {
        $this->load->set_model('model_name');
    }

}

class loader
{

    public function set_model($name)
    {
        {controller_class}->models[$name] = new model();
    }

}
```

The controller class is instantiated without assigning it to a variable, but just:

```
new controller();
```

And then the action is executed from within the controller class.

Comment: You could inject the `controller` object in the constructor of the `loader` object; `$this->load = new loader($this);`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass a reference to `$this` into `set_model()`

```
class controller
{

    public $models;

    private $load;

    public function __construct() 
    {
        $this->load = new loader();
    }

    public function action_being_run()
    {
        $this->load->set_model('model_name', $this);
    }

}

class loader
{

    public function set_model($name, &$this)
    {
        {controller_class}->models[$name] = new model();
    }

}
```

You also need to change `public $model` to `public $models`. There are probably other ways to achieve what you want, by either extending a class or just using magic methods to access the model.

Comment: Thanks! That must be the only thing i haven't thought of. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
class tester{
  public function lame(){
    return 'super lame';
  }
}
function after(){
  return 'after function';
}
$tst = new tester; $tst->afterVar = 'anything'; $tst->afterFun = 'after';
echo $wh->afterVar;
echo $wh->afterFun();
```